# Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

I uninstalled rails and then try to install it again. But I got this error when doing bundle install:

Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Rubygems is unavailable due to a DNS outage, see: https://twitter.com/rubygems_status

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it's the case for other people or not but i'm mentioning it for the sake of help - I got the error some days ago and i got it again today - I was very worry because nothing seems to be wrong and i could not find any help - But then i observed that some sites are not opening while some are working fine - I contacted my Internet provider and asked them to check why other sites are not working - The reason was that the Internet providers has changed their some settings due to which site's servers which were in the blacklisted country IPs didn't got work (i mean ,that makes sense too) and after my complain other sites also **started working** . Now intentionally i check the "bundle install" command and It started fetching the gems information from "https://rubygems.org/" so I think you should check that some other sites if you're facing the same problem try to contact you internet provider -

> The Main reason for the above error is that your system is unable to
>   fetch gems information from https://rubygems.org/ website